# Why is using rawData slower than direct file access

Tags: c#

I forgot my password of a .pfx x509 certificate, so I decided I wanted to try to bruteforce it. So I went to test and wrote the following code:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                var cert = new X509Certificate2("D:/file.pfx", i.ToString(), X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
                Console.WriteLine("Found it: " + i);
            }catch
            {

            }
        }
```

I know it's far from optimal, but that's not what my question is about. It was a bit slow, so I thought, I can use the rawData overload instead of giving it the pathname. So I did the following code:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                cert = new X509Certificate2(buffer, i.ToString(), X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
                Console.WriteLine("Found it: " + i);
            }catch
            {}
        }
```

Where `buffer` is a `byte[]`; Outside of the loop I just loaded it in  with the raw data from the file with a `BinaryReader`.

Only this code is like 3 times slower. Why is that?

**Edit**: I've ran this code like a 100 times now, so it's not just a random coincidence.

Comment: It seems your title and text are contradictory, which one is faster? The raw data variant or the one where you pass the path?

Comment: I'm sorry they are indeed. Using Direct File access is actually faster ;)

Comment: I would imagine it's because the disk cache/windows manager are handling things more effectively then your simple byte cache. Interesting though.

Comment: Yeah although that doesn't make sense, because even if it is caching the disk, it doesn't need to cache anything because I'm just using a byte array. I imagine the result of a disk i/o operation is a byte array too.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't need to read the whole file to check if your password is correct.

Comment: How confident are you on your benchmarking?

Comment: I'm pretty confident. I ran this code a lot of times now, and the difference between those two are ALWAYS significant (200-300% difference). Like 5 secs in the first case, and 10-15 secs in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the disk cache is unmanaged, therefore faster?